# Запуск python-скриптов cron'ом

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.x, cron

Никак не могу настроить крон на запуск `python`-скриптов. Делаю так:

```
* * * * * cd путь_до_проекта && venv/bin/python cron.py
```

Если написать `* * * * * cd путь_до_проекта && echo 'hello there' >> demo_cron.txt`, то все хорошо работает.

**В чем может быть причина ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv, второй ответ (не принятый) мне больше нравится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* * * *  /путь_до_питона/python путь_до_проекта/cron.py
```